# Get content between { } braces

Tags: ruby

How can I get the content in between "{ }" in Ruby? For example,

> I love {you}

How can I fetch the element "you"? If I want to replace the content, say change "you" to "her", how should I do that? Probably using `gsub`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regular expressions are the way to go with gsub. Something like:

```
existingString.gsub(/\{(.*?)\}/) { "her" }
```

Answer (score 6):

```
replacements = {
  'you' => 'her',
  'angels' => 'demons',
  'ice cream' => 'puppies',
}

my_string = "I love {you}.\nYour voice is like {angels} singing.\nI would love to eat {ice cream} with you sometime!"

replacements.each do |source, replacement|
  my_string.gsub! "{#{source}}", replacement
end

puts my_string
# => I love her.
# => Your voice is like demons singing.
# => I would love to eat puppies with you sometime!
```

Comment: This is the only generic solution. +1!

Answer (score 4):

The simple way to get the content from the inside of the `{...}` is:

```
str = 'I love {you}'
str[/{(.+)}/, 1] # => "you"
```

That basically says, "grab everything inside a leading `{` to a trailing `}`. It's not real sophisticated and can be fooled by nested `{}` pairs.

Replacing the target string can be done various ways:

```
replace_str = 'her'
'I love {you}'.sub('you', replace_str) # => "I love {her}"
```

A simple `sub` will replace the first occurrence of the target string with the replacement text.

You could use a regex instead of the string:

```
'I love you {you}'.sub(/you/, replace_str) # => "I love her {you}"
```

If there are multiple occurrences of the target string then use a bit more text to locate it. This uses the wrapping delimiters to locate it, and then replaces them also. There are other ways to do this, but I'd do it like:

```
'I love you {you}'.sub(/{.+}/, "{#{ replace_str }}") # => "I love you {her}"
```

Alex Wayne's answer came close but didn't go all the way: Ruby's [`gsub`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html#method-i-gsub) has a really nice feature, where you can pass it a regex and a hash, and it will replace all the occurrences of the regex matches with the values in the hash:

```
hash = {
  'I' => 'She',
  'love' => 'loves',
  'you' => 'me'
}
str.gsub(Regexp.union(hash.keys), hash) # => "She loves {me}"
```

That's really powerful when you want to take a template and quickly replace all the placeholders in it.

Answer (score 2):

You can always use .index:

```
a = 'I love {bill gates}'
a[a.index('{')+1..a.index('}')-1]
```

The last line just says get 'a' from right after the first occurrence of '{' and right before the first occurrence of '}'. It is important to note, however, that this will only get the text between the first occurrences of {}. So it will work for your above example.

I would use indexing also to add something new between the {}s.

That would look something like:

```
a[0..a.index('{')] + 'Steve Jobs' + a[a.index('}')..-1]
```

Again this only works for the first occurrence of '{' and '}'.

Michael G.

Answer (score 2):

why not use some template engine like: https://github.com/defunkt/mustache

note that ruby can do this for `%{}`:

```
"foo = %{foo}" % { :foo => 'bar' }
#=> "foo = bar"
```

and finally do not forget to check existing [ruby template engines](https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/template_engines) - do not reinvent the wheel!

Comment: The OP wants to get the content of something between curly braces and optionally change it. How does that relate to templating in the OP's question?

Comment: call it how you want but that's a template => http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template